# Reactor Kafka to consume message and send it to another topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, reactor-kafka

What I would like to achieve:

- 1: Consume messages from Kafka
- 2: Apply some business transformation (uppercase in this example)
- 3A: Save transformed message inside reactive database using non blocking reactive repository
- 3B: Send transformed message back to Kafka in another topic

hopefully 3A and 3B in parallel, since there is no dependency between them (dependency only on step 2)

What I tried:

- using project `Reactor Kafka`, (and I hope to stick with Reactor Kafka only) I coded this

```
package org.example;

import org.example.repository.MyReactiveRepository;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.kafka.receiver.KafkaReceiver;
import reactor.kafka.sender.KafkaSender;

@Service
public class MyConsumerSender implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyConsumerSender.class);

    @Autowired
    private KafkaReceiver<String, String> kafkaReceiver;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaSender<String, String> kafkaSender;

    @Autowired
    private MyReactiveRepository myReactiveRepository;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        consume().subscribe();
    }

    Flux<String> consume() {
        return kafkaReceiver.receive()  //step 1
                .flatMap(rec -> { String transformedString = rec.value().toUpperCase(); //step 2
                    Mono<String> repositorySaveMono = myReactiveRepository.save(transformedString); //step 3A
                    Mono<String> kafkaSendMono = kafkaSender.send(transformedString); //step 3B, I am having issue here
                    return Mono.zip(repositorySaveMono, kafkaSendMono);
                });
    }

}
```

However, I am having a hard time with step 3B. I am facing issue with `kafkaSender.send()` API. Could you please help?

Comment: Hello, maybe it would worth to mention what kind of issue you are facing :) it would be much easier to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Reactor Kafka provides several interfaces for Kafka producers (senders).

### Consume and send data as a stream

`<T> Flux<SenderResult<T>> send(Publisher<? extends SenderRecord<K, V, T>> records)`

In this case we create `kafkaOutboundStream` by consuming messages from source topic and pass it to `kafkaSender.send()` that subscribes to this `Flux` and sends messages to Kafka.

In this case we can apply processing logic before or after sending data to Kafka. In the following `processRecord` is applied before.

```
Flux<SenderResult<ReceiverOffset>> transform() {
    Flux<SenderRecord<String, String, ReceiverOffset>> kafkaOutboundStream = kafkaReceiver.receive()
            .flatMap(sourceRecord ->
                    processRecord(sourceRecord)
                            .map(resultRecord -> SenderRecord.create(
                                    new ProducerRecord<>("destination-topic", sourceRecord.key(), resultRecord),
                                    sourceRecord.receiverOffset())
                            )
            );

    return kafkaSender.send(kafkaOutboundStream)
            .doOnNext(sourceRecord -> sourceRecord.correlationMetadata().acknowledge());
}

private Mono<String> processRecord(ReceiverRecord<String, String> sourceRecord) {
    String transformed = sourceRecord.value().toUpperCase();
    return save(transformed)
            .thenReturn(transformed);
}
```

### Consume and send data as multiple streams (fun-out)

In case we want to send data to Kafka and save to database in parallel, we would need to "fan-out" source `Flux` to consume and process it in parallel by 2 different subscriptions.

```
Flux<Tuple2<SenderResult<ReceiverOffset>, String>> transform() {
    Flux<ReceiverRecord<String, String>> source = kafkaReceiver.receive()
            .publish()
            .autoConnect(2);

    var kafkaOutboundStream = source
            .map(sourceRecord -> SenderRecord.create(
                    new ProducerRecord<>("destination-topic", sourceRecord.key(), sourceRecord.value().toUpperCase()),
                    sourceRecord.receiverOffset())
            );

    var kafkaSenderStream = kafkaSender.send(kafkaOutboundStream);

    var dbSaveStream = source
            .flatMap(sourceRecord -> save(sourceRecord.value().toUpperCase()));

    return Flux.zip(kafkaSenderStream, dbSaveStream)
            .doOnNext(resultRecord -> resultRecord.getT1().correlationMetadata().acknowledge());
}
```

In this case you would need to `acknowledge` record when both operations are completed.

### Consume and send data record by record

`KafkaOutbound<K, V> createOutbound().send(Publisher<? extends ProducerRecord<K, V>> records)`

As an alternative, you can process data and send to kafka using `kafkaSender.createOutbound().send()` that is more close to the code you shared.

```
Flux<Tuple2<String, String>> transform2() {
    return kafkaReceiver.receive()
            .flatMap(sourceRecord -> {
                String transformed = sourceRecord.value().toUpperCase();
                var resultRecord = new ProducerRecord<>("destination-topic", sourceRecord.key(), transformed);
                return Mono.zip(sendToTopic(resultRecord), save(transformed))
                        .doOnNext(rec -> sourceRecord.receiverOffset().acknowledge());
            });

}

private Mono<String> sendToTopic(ProducerRecord<String, String> message) {
    return kafkaSender.createOutbound()
            .send(Mono.just(message))
            .then()
            .thenReturn(message.value());
}
```

Comment: Hello @Alex, thank you for this nice writing (as always). Really like solution 2 and 3, many thanks. As for solution 1, I have couple of questions if you allow me. After investigation online, it seems it is not optimal, and actually, has performance issue, as we are saving entities one by one inside the flatmap, (which can create many extra connections or transactions depending on the actual reactive repositories) as opposed to saving the flux directly. Before I accept and award the bounty, could you suggest a solution based on ```saveAll```, which looks more like:

Comment: ```kafkaSender.send(myReactiveRepository.saveAll(kafkaReceiver.receive().map(one ->transiofrm(one) [...]``` + manual acknowledge please?

Comment: not sure what you mean by "performance issue" and "many extra connections" but I would say that solution #1 has better reliability because it's easier to handle errors and clear and more clear when to ack source offset. You can't do `saveAll(kafkaReceiver.receive())` because this is unbounded stream of data and there is no all.

Comment: As for connections - 1. you can control concurrency of the `flatMap`, 2. - typically number of  connections is controlled by the pool of the underlining db client

Comment: If you want to process in batches - use `buffer(N)` operator before `flatMap`.

Comment: Very clear explanation. However, I did try a simple ```kafkaSender.send(reactiveCassandraRepository.saveAll(kafkaReceiver.receive().map(one -> one.value().toUpperCase()``` and it is much faster than ```save(transformed).thenReturn(transformed);```. I did couple of benchmark test with mongo/cassandra/elastic and all three of those reactive repositories yield better performance (i.e., save 20 million of record inside the DB + send back 20 millions of transformed message back in MUCH less time) But I agree this is a bit outside of the original question, was just asking if you had that handy @Alex

Comment: Not sure I understand how the above code works. `Flux` returned from `kafkaReceiver.receive()`  would never complete

Comment: As for performance, "Consume and send data as stream" should support higher throughput.

Comment: Thanks @Alex for the comment. For sure, tested solution where everything is as a flux (and it does complete) vs your solution 1, and the order of improvement is drastic. I would invite you to give this a try (totally on your free time and if you are interested of course).